# Issue while using 9 patch

Tags: android, layout, canvas, background, nine-patch

I have an app, that to chatting. I need to create bubbles. I did it with `nine-Patch` image but it was not useful because I need little triangle on right (left) of the bubble and when `nine-Patch` stretches the image the triangle also gets stretched. This is the problem.
Can I Draw background of Layout with `canvas` or etc. ?

Comment: I have created 9patch with arrow on right and left and it working like charm

Comment: when creating the 9patch, don't include the triangle region as being "stretchable"

Comment: I'd say it is more an issue with the use of the 9-patch than with the notion of 9-patch itself. also, your title makes it look like a rant, perhaps you should change it to illustrate what you are expecting ?

Comment: I need to hold triangle part on bubbles center. Ms Biraj Zalavadia, how you'd make nine-patch image. please tell me

Answer (score 1):

**Try this ones**

*download it and do not forget to rename it with image1.9.png*

*This may not working give me your mail id i will mail you*

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok. Thank u for answer. But I have olso created such nine-patch, but I need to hold triangle part on bubbles center. my email: agshin.h@gmail.com

Comment: send your original images i will try to make it 9patch an send to your mail my mail id is birajzalavadia@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Also, check this one and rename it as .9.png

[image: bubble.9.png]

It was created using the draw9patch tool located in sdk\tools folder.